# Organize Entries in Admin Panel

Tags: entries

I'm trying to sort the entries. Is there a way to do this without using the filters given? Can this be done manually?

Comment: Can you provide more details? It's quite unclear as to what you're asking... What do you mean "without using the filters given"? What do you mean "manually"?

Answer (score 2):

Are you wanting to drag entries up and down to sort them? As far as I'm aware the only way to order manually would be to use a Structure and not a Channel.

Alternatively if you just want to manually order them for use in a for loop (such as showing news items), you could add an entries field somewhere (in a global, a news page, a homepage, or somewhere else convenient). Then you can reference that list for your entries output. That would let you manually order them.

Comment: Yes, I am using a channel with multiple entries like this-                              {% for entry in craft.entries.section('work').limit(5) %}                                   <a href="{{ entry.url }}">  <div class="mainImage" style="background-image:url({{ entry.mainImages.first.url }});">                                                {% endfor %}   They are sorted by when they were created and I want to sort them by image.

Comment: So in this instance you could add a field to the page they appear on, then call that field instead of craft.entries.section....

E.g. {% for work in entry.workList.limit(5) %}

Comment: I created a field called List for the work entries. Should I give them a number put them in order and then call them like this-{% for work in entry.workList.limit(5) %}. That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Stan your code looks fine. You shouldn't need to give them a number or anything, you can just drag and drop to reorder the list. Can I ask what version number of Craft you're using?

Comment: I'm using the most recent version.

Comment: I'm not able to re-order them though.

Comment: Darn. Can you provide a screenshot your entry screen?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3oaky49aevyxkha/unnamed.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cp8xoy2p3fyzh7y/unnamed-1.png?dl=0

Comment: ah I see. Do you have a screenshot of the entry with the field added to it?

Comment: Yes-https://www.dropbox.com/s/2yi9qmel5r464b5/Screen%20Shot%202016-01-22%20at%201.16.53%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you add the workList entry field to the entry you're loading on the front-end?

Comment: Do you mean like this?  If I do this, my images no longer appear on the homepage.                                                                                                         {% for entry in craft.entries.section('workList').limit(5) %}
      <div class="header_image">
          <a href="{{ entry.url }}"> <span class="title"> {{ entry.heading }} </span>
          <div class="mainImage" style="background-image:url({{ (entry.mainImages.first.url) }} )"> </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}

Comment: Shouid I add the workList field to the homepage where the images are being shown?

Comment: Yep, you need to add the field to the page you're displaying. So if you are showing all the worklist entries on the homepage, then add your field to that page. Then you can output whatever entries you've selected in that field.

Comment: Not sure what to do next. What field type should 'workList' be?